# Don't know where the file is to begin debugging c#

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a console application in Visual Studio Code. I have tried many things to get to this point and now i cannot figure out what this means.

```
${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll
```

It is in the launch.json under

```
.NET Core launch (console).
```

As the value for: "program"

I know where ${workspaceRoot} is but i have no idea what my project target framework is or how to figure it out, and there is no bin file inside my work space root.

Here is the debug config file:

```
"name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
"type": "coreclr",
"request": "launch",
"preLaunchTask": "build",
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
"args": [],
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
"stopAtEntry": false,
"console": "internalConsole"
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? FYI, no `.dll` is not a C# program

Comment: I see this used in all other c# Visual studio code debugging tutorials.

Comment: What is the error? What problem are you having? Do you not know what to put in for the `target-framework` and `project-name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the framework in the project.json or .csproj.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#frameworks

If run `dotnet restore && dotnet build` in your project root. It will generate a bin folder (if you did not modify the output file).

For example: My project called Temp, I have a csproj with the value `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>`. My `program` value is set to `${workspaceRoot}\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Temp.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a same problem but I solved it by changing the value of

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/temp.dll",
```

by

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MyProject.dll",
```

change `.dll` file name as your project file name. That's it.